# How to show a particular activity when onClick a push message is received from pushwoosh

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I set push Woosh notification in my project.but when I click on Push message,just main activity opens!how can I click on push message and open which activity I want?!
Also I implement all the methods of push woosh and used this link for running it http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-android-sdk

my sample code is ...

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        //Re-register receivers on resume
        registerReceivers();
        super.onResume();
        if(Constants.login_status==true) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, CartsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        //Unregister receivers on pause
        unregisterReceivers();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "navigate" through the app. You could check in main activity (onCreate) if the activity was opened from push (and if yes) you could open the next activity (sending the deeplink) and so on until you reached the desire activity.

Comment: even an activity contains several fragments?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. You could check it on main activity, if the user is logged navigate to the next activity you want, if not open login activity.

Comment: I tried launch mode and deeplinking for acitivities .it solved my problem.